# How to prove quantum ${\cal N}=4$ Super-Yang-Mills is superconformal?

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills, non-perturbative, superconformality

I'm especially interested in elegant illuminating proofs which don't involve a lot of straightforward technical computations

Also, does a non-perturbative proof exist?

Comment: Regard it as an N=1 super Yang-Mills theory with three adjoint chiral superfields, and apply the non-perturbative analysis of [Leigh-Strassler](http://arXiv.org/abs/hep-th/9503121).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In any supersymmetric theory you can choose the gauge coupling to be the coefficient of $W_\alpha^2$ in the superpotential. This gauge coupling runs only at one-loop, which is a fundamental consequence of the non-renormalization theorems. The other possible running coefficients are the kinetic terms, $Z(\mu)QQ^\dagger$. These generally get renormalized to all orders in perturbation theory.

In $\mathcal{N}=4$ the one-loop coefficient is zero. This is trivial (just counting the fields). Hence, the gauge coupling (as defined above) does not run. But $\mathcal{N}=4$ relates the gauge particles with the chiral superfields (all the matter particles sit in one big representation of $\mathcal{N}=4$) and so the latter cannot get renormalized either.

This is a slick and intuitive argument... Similar logic operates in many $\mathcal{N}=2$ theories as well.

Comment: Nice answer. Can you provide a ref pls? Do I understand correctly this argument is perturbative only? If so, is there a way to extend it to a nonperturbative one?

Comment: It is non-perturbative, because the gauge coupling does not run non-perturbatively. I have not seen it explicitly written anywhere, but I am sure I am (by far) not the first one who had this thought :)

Comment: Your argument is definitely nicer :)

Comment: Yuji: I think you may need to resort to this argument anyway, even if you do Leigh-Strassler. This is because the latter only implies a one-dimensional line of CFTs, but it does not prove that this one-dimensional line coincides with the line on which N=4 sits. So at some point you have to invoke the higher symmetry.

Comment: Ok, so can you provide a ref to the nonrenormalization theorem you are using?

Comment: Page 96 in http://www.physics.uc.edu/~argyres/661/susy1996.pdf reviews the argument. In general you can prove that it is one-loop+non-perturbative contributions. In N=4 since there is no 
one-loop there is no \Lambda and so also the non-perturbative contributions are absent.

Comment: Yes that's right. The flavor of the argument there seems very similar to what I said. I assume a similar approach can be taken to theories in 3d, or more generally, any theory where the notion of holomorphy makes sense.